# Evaluate contents of object

Tags: python, tkinter, eval

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet application using Python3 and am having difficulty setting it up to be able to do cross-cell functions, such as:

```
a0+2
```

where a0 is a tkinter textbox containing a string. I have made a dictionary mapping each address (a0, a1, a2, etc) to the cell object, but am not sure whether to make the program parse the string looking for an address string, or whether there is some very neat `eval()` trick. I have tried using `eval()`, but I keep getting an error

`TypeError: globals must be a real dict; try eval(expr, {}, mapping)`

No matter where I put the dictionary, or even if I tried to use a global cast. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: You would have to parse the string within each text box to determine whether it contains literal strings, integers or references to cells. Once you extract the cell address/key you can access the value in that cell(dict lookup) which would need to be parsed as well.

Comment: Check out this highly-rated [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/355045-spreadsheet).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe look into using something like [SymPy](http://sympy.org) rather than `eval()`. It should allow the use to do calculation in the cells as long as you can link up the symbols (like `a0` here).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use eval to evaluate the formulas. It enables people to put almost any python code into the spreadsheet, meaning every spreadsheet you have is capable of doing untold damages to your computer system. It's a very very bad idea.

Comment: Or expressed more generally, **do not use eval, ever** - unless you know exactly what you are doing and have explored all other options.

Comment: I really hate the knee-jerk reaction just about everyone on SO has about the use of `eval`. Yes, it could be dangerous in some situations, but that is NOT a concern for everyone in every application. It's part of the language for a reason and can be very useful.

Comment: @martineau: Yes. But in this case it *is* a concern. There is nothing knee-jerk about it. I also explained why. After 11 years with Python, very little I say about it is knee-jerk.

Comment: Well, all I can say, with about an equal number of years of Python experience, is that I disagree with your assessment. The Python `TypeError` error message even suggests its use. Not only that, other fairly well respected Python developers have [suggested](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/355045-spreadsheet/) using it for precisely for this purpose.

Comment: Running eval on arbitrary user input? Nobody sane would suggest that. Your link talks about "spreadsheet style logic" That's an important difference.

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand for which purpose you try to use eval. Simple example is if we have three cell for example:

```
a0=3; a1=2; a3=a0+a1
```

Just sum a0 and a1 I don't mind where you will not get without eval()

Comment: The problem is that one cell may have the _string_ `"a0+a1"`. The OP wants to somehow evaluate that string to get the sum.